# Howto iterate over more than one element in python's for loop

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

The idea is quite simple, I want to do something like this:

```
for elem1, elem2, elem3 in list:
    <some code>
```

For this to work we need that list would be a list of 3-iterables, something like this:

```
list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

But, what can I do if this list is just a regular list?

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Is there any fast and simple way of transform this regular list into the list of 3-iterables so the loop would work? Or n-iterables, I use 3 here just as an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python ?

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry if I have asked the same, I tried to search before asking but I didn't found anything

Answer (score 5):

Use the `grouper` recipe from itertools:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

And something like:

```
for a, b, c in grouper(3, some_list):
    pass # whatever
```

Comment: Thank you, really simple and elegant solution.

Comment: @ole it's my preferred as it's nice and generic for iterables - but yeah - loads of options in the duplicated post!

Comment: your solution is the best for me, but this is just my opinion